# Output of robot_pose_ekf jumps uncontrollably

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to fuse data from a magnetometer, wheel odometry and a GPS sensor using the robot_pose_ekf. Since I would like to take advantage of the fact that both magnetometer and GPS are defined within an absolute reference frame, I switched to a fork by clearpath robotics which is publicly available.

I publish my wheel odometry on topic /odom:

```
        dat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0,self.th)
        quaternion = Quaternion(dat[0],dat[1],dat[2],dat[3])
        odom = Odometry()
        odom.header.stamp = now
        odom.header.frame_id = "odom_combined"
        odom.pose.pose.position.x = self.x
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = self.y
        odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0
        odom.pose.pose.orientation = quaternion
        odom.pose.covariance= [0.000001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0.000001, 0, 0, 0, 0,    
                               0, 0, 0.000001, 0, 0, 0,   
                               0, 0, 0, 0.000001, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000001, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000001]  
        odom.twist.covariance = [99999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 99999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 99999, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 99999, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 99999, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99999] 
        
        odom.child_frame_id = "base_footprint"
        self.odomPub.publish(odom)
```

My gps in topic /gps

```
        odom = Odometry()
        odom.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        odom.header.frame_id = "odom_combined"
        (x, y) = self.converter.LatLong2UTM(self.lat, self.lon)
        odom.pose.pose.position.x = x
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = y
        odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0
        
        dat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, 0)
        odom.pose.pose.orientation = Quaternion(dat[0],dat[1],dat[2],dat[3])
        
        odom.child_frame_id = "base_footprint"
        odom.pose.covariance =[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  # covariance on gps_x
                               0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,    # covariance on gps_y
                               0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,    # covariance on gps_z
                               0, 0, 0, 99999, 0, 0,  # large covariance on rot x
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 99999, 0,  # large covariance on rot y
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99999]  # large covariance on rot z
        odom.twist.covariance = [99999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 99999, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 99999, 0, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 99999, 0, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 99999, 0, 
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99999] 
        self.pub.publish(odom)
```

and my compass data in /imu_data

```
    im = Imu()
    ori = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, math.radians(bearing))
    qua = Quaternion(ori[0],ori[1],ori[2],ori[3])
    im.header.frame_id = "imu_data"
    im.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    im.orientation = qua
    im.orientation_covariance = [0.000001, 0, 0,  
                                 0, 0.000001, 0,  
                                 0, 0, 0.000001]  
    
    # Switch others off for now.
    im.angular_velocity_covariance = [99999, 0, 0,
                                      0, 99999, 0,
                                      0, 0, 99999] 


    im.linear_acceleration_covariance = [99999, 0, 0,
                                         0, 99999, 0,
                                         0, 0, 99999]     
    
    self.imupub.publish(im)
```

I've been toying around with the covariance values a lot, but they don't seem to have any influence on my particular problem..

Furthermore, I've had problems with robot_pose_ekf giving me transformation errors, even when I set the header.frame_id of the imu-message to base_footprint:

```
    Could not transform imu message from base_footprint to base_footprint.
```

Therefore I created a static transform publisher relating the imu_data directly to base_footprint.

Now the EKF is giving me some output, and at the beginning /odom, /odom_combined and /imu converge nicely. As soon as I turn one of the wheels however, the pose output of the EKF begins jumping around uncontrollably (with the heading being updated correctly). It settles on some rather arbitrary looking point when I stop turning the wheel.

Furthermore the EKF reports that diagnostics has discovered a potential problem, which according to the docs is due to /odom and /imu being too far apart. They however are just fine and nicely aligned; it's only the kalman filter that misbehaves.

I've had the same problem with the official github version when attaching the GPS to the /vo topic, which is in fact the reason I switched to another fork.

Any ideas? I've been at this all day.

**EDIT**: The problem is definitely related to the /odom/pose/orientation calculated from the wheel encoders. If I switch off the compass entirely in the launch file, the filtered position still jumps. If I however set the odom/pose/orientation to a constant (0,0,0) and thus not include my odometry direction measurements, the jumping subsides (both with compass on and off).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148021/output-of-robot_pose_ekf-jumps-uncontrollably/) by [Simon Harst](https://answers.ros.org/users/12491/simon-harst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't formally announced this yet, but you might want to try this:

http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization

It will let you choose to only use parts of your sensor messages.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simon Harst](https://answers.ros.org/users/12491/simon-harst/) on 2014-04-06**:
Wow, that looks really cool on first glance! Will look into it promptly and report back..

**Comment by [Simon Harst](https://answers.ros.org/users/12491/simon-harst/) on 2014-04-06**:
Kudos! Works perfectly out of the box. One more question, though: If I understand your code correctly, the filter gets initialized with a zero value and is then updated differentially. There doesn't happen to be a way of initializing the pose with my gps and the orientation with the magnetometer?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-07**:
Ha! It's one of the very first things on my list. I will let you know when it's implemented. I plan to parameterize the differential updating.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-07**:
In the meantime, you can throw together a quick callback for your GPS and magnetometer and use them to manually set the initial state of your robot by issuing a PoseWithCovarianceStamped message to the set_pose topic. It's there to allow manual resets of the entire state.

**Comment by [Simon Harst](https://answers.ros.org/users/12491/simon-harst/) on 2014-04-07**:
You, kind Sir, are a lifesaver.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-08**:
Updated. I added new launch file parameters that let you control which variables from each sensor are handled differentially. If you have any issues/feedback, feel free to contact me via email (available on my Github account).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that the transformation between the `imu_data` frame and `base_footprint` is correct. In particular the rotation is crucial. I'm also not sure if the switching off of angular velocity and linear acceleration does what you think it does. robot_pose_ekf is not a general purpose ekf but was written for a specific purpose for the PR2 robot. I have no clue about the clearpath fork though.

**Edit:** I thought I had updated my answer before, but it seems it got lost...

I strongly suggest to look at previous questions surrounding robot_pose_ekf here on answers.ros.org. It has been discussed previously what robot_pose_ekf does and when it doesn't. In particular the way it handles covariances is not neccessarily what you expect. And it probably is also best if you check a little bit in the code to see what parts of your input messages is read and how it is used.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Simon Harst](https://answers.ros.org/users/12491/simon-harst/) on 2014-04-03**:
Thank you very much for your reply. The IMU has no effect on the jumping. In fact, I can switch it completely off and still the jumping remains.
Is there any other way I can signal to the filter that I don't have data for angular vel. and linear acc. ?